# Assign this to self in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, this, variable-assignment

I am currently writing a jQuery UI plugin and investigate therefore the existent jQuery UI sources.
In the `_create` method of the accordion plugin `this` is assigned to `self` [(link to source)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js#L37), but then both `this` and `self` are used side by side in that method. So why do they chose to assign to `self` at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all about the context. In the function itself `self` and `this` refer to the same object but in the event handlers `this` refers to the DOM element the event is targeting. By assigning the value of `this` to `self` it leaves them free to refer to either the widget object or to the DOM element within those event handlers.

If you look closely you'll notice that within the context of the function they use `self` exclusively and while in the anonymous functions (event handlers) they use both `this` and `self` to refer to the DOM element or to the Widget, respectively.

Comment: Recently stumbled upon something I didn't know so far. Browsers actually already implement the ´self´ variable. It is a reference to the window object. So overriding self might not be a good idea. It got me into hells kitchen, because from the moment on, that I was using self, also the reference to window changed!

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly know how JQuery UI plugins work, but what I could imagine is the following scenario. I think they wanted to keep a reference to the Widget object without overwriting `this` (changing the scope). When the function is executed the scope is no longer the Widget object but a DOM Element. Therefore they can easily add classes and everything using `this` as a reference. Before that happens they rescue the widget objcet scope using closure and assigning the value of `this` (now still being the widget object, when the code is interpreted) to the local variable `self`. Now using self they can change fields on the object.